# Python Popen output to a c program, fget read the same stdin in a loop

Tags: python, c, subprocess, popen, fgets

I expect the c program print the received 3 lines. But the result is that the c program print `from c program:33333333` nonstoppedly. I don't know why `fgets()` didn't consume `stdin` after executtion.

```
# pin.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen("/home/jchn/pstdin",stdin=PIPE,stdout=None)
p.stdin.write("11111111")
p.stdin.write("22222222")
p.stdin.write("33333333")
```

Content of **pstdin.c**

```
# pstdin.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[10];
    FILE* fd = fopen("output","w");
    while (1){  
        fgets(a,10,stdin);
        printf("--from c program--:%s",a);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(1)` is an infinite loop, you have no stop condition

```
while(fgets(a,10,stdin) != NULL)
{
  printf("--from c program--:%s",a);
}
```

Comment: I thought that fgets() will blocking wait until new stdin is given.

Comment: @jvchn You are doing fgets() which is right but doing it in a `while(1)` is not right since you don't have exit condition

Comment: @jvchn: you won't get an exception like in Python if `fgets()` fails. You have to check its return value to detect EOF or an error (you could use `feof()`, `ferror()` to distinguish the two).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no stop condition, `fgets()` fails to read but the `a` array still contains the last string i.e. `"33333333"` so it keeps printing that.

When there is nothing more to read, `fgets()` returns `NULL`, so you can check against that as **Gopi** already mentioned.

So your c program would run fine if you do this

```
# pstdin.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[10];
    FILE* fd = fopen("output","w");
    if (fd == NULL)
        return -1; /* check this before accessing the file please */
    while (fgets(a, 10, stdin))
        printf("--from c program--:%s",a);
}
```